# Salesforce 1 Android Open Camera

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm developing a visualforce that needs to use the camera from salesforce 1 and then upload the image as a chatter feed. I'm using

```
<input id="filePicker"  class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

but it is not working.

There is a way to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Coincidentally, I have written article on same and its working in my Nexus5 and IPhone6. Can you confirm if it works for you ?

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/access-camera-and-audio-recorder-of-mobile-device-in-visualforce-and-upload-as-chatter-file/

I am using this syntax :

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!cont.VersionData}"  accept="image/*;capture=camera" filename="{!cont.Title}" />
```

Comment: That do not work with my mobile device, it is a Motorola G2. I'm still looking for a solution.