# Salesforce1: Unable to access mobile camera

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have written code to access camera from VF page. It is working fine in laptop browser and mobile browser. But when I am trying the same VF page in Salesforce1 app it is not accessing camera.I am using Andriod OS.

I tried 2 approaches, both are not working.

**Approach 1:** Using `<apex:inputFile accept="image/*;capture=camera" />`

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="CameraAccess2" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        Enter File Description
        <p>
            <apex:inputText value="{!AttachmentName}" />
            <apex:inputFile value="{!attachmentObj.Body}"  accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <apex:commandButton  action="{!saveFile}" value="Save File" />
        </p>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class CameraAccess{
    public Attachment attachmentObj {get;set;}
    public String AttachmentName {get;set;}
    public CameraAccess() {
        attachmentObj = new Attachment();
    }     

    public PageReference saveFile()
    {
        attachmentObj.ParentId = '003J000000wGwBR';
        attachmentObj.Name = AttachmentName +'.jpg';
        insert attachmentObj;
        return new PageReference('/003J000000wGwBR');
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:** Using Javascript WebCam api.

Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryPackageReport, 'package/media/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}"/>

<title>Webcam</title>
<div  style="background-color:#FFF">
    <div  style="padding-top: 2%;padding-bottom: 1%;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3" >
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px" id="snap" >Capture</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px;display:none" id="new">Retake</button>    
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:10px;display:none" id="upload">Upload</button>
        </div>


        <div >
            <select class="form-control" style="margin-top:10px" id="videoSource"></select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 2%;padding-bottom: 1%;" >
        <div align="center">
            <canvas id="canvas" style="display:none;border-radius: 15px;" width="240" height="200"></canvas>
            <video class="myvideo" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" style="border-radius: 15px;"></video> 
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div id="el_loading" style="display:none;position: fixed;top:0;background-color: #fbfbfb; height:100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;">
        <div  style="top: 50%; width: 91px;  margin: 20% 47%;"> 
            <img  src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..."/>
            <span>Saving...</span>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div  id="myModal1">
    <div style="padding-top: 5%">  
        <div style="background-color: #2AD67B;color: white;border-radius: 7%;">
            <div  style="background-color: #2AD67B;color: white;border-radius: 7%;">
                <button class="close" onclick="hideTheBoxComponent();" style="color:white" type="button">&times;</button>
                <p style="margin-left: 39%;font-size: large;margin-top: 4%;">
                     Image Saved
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>   
    function hideTheBoxComponent(){
        $("#myModal1").modal('hide'); 
    }

    function showDialogComponent(){
        $("#myModal1").modal({
          "backdrop"  : "static",
          "keyboard"  : true,
          "show"      : true 
        });
    }

    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
            };

        // Capture Snap Photo
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 250, 200);
            // Littel effects
            $('#video').hide();
            $('#canvas').show();
            $('#snap').hide();
            $('#new').show();
            $('#upload').show();
        });

        // Capture New Photo
        document.getElementById("new").addEventListener("click", function() {
            $('#video').show();
            $('#canvas').hide();
            $('#snap').show();
            $('#new').hide();
            $('#upload').hide();
        });



    }, false);

    'use strict';

    var videoElement = document.querySelector('video');    
    var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    function gotSources(sourceInfos) {
      for (var i = 0; i !== sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = sourceInfo.id;
        if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video') {
          option.text = sourceInfo.label || 'camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
          videoSelect.appendChild(option);
        } else {
          console.log('Some other kind of source: ', sourceInfo);
        }
      }
    }

    if (typeof MediaStreamTrack === 'undefined'){
      alert('This browser does not support MediaStreamTrack.\n\nTry Chrome Canary.');
    } else {
      MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);
    }

    function successCallback(stream) {
      window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
      videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      videoElement.play();
    }

    function errorCallback(error){
      console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
    }

    function start(){
      if (!!window.stream) {
        videoElement.src = null;
        window.stream.stop();
      }
      var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
      var constraints = {

        video: {
          optional: [{sourceId: videoSource}]
        }
      };
      navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }
    videoSelect.onchange = start;
    start();
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: May be this question can help you (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87478/how-to-access-mobile-camera-from-android-phone-vf-page)

Comment: I am doing the same thing but its not working.

Comment: then i think its a known issue (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3MFAA0)

Answer (score 1):

No, This is not possible with the Salesforce1 app in Android.
When I checked the permissions of salesforce1 app, I found that there is no permission given for accessing Camera.

### **Permission Name** : Take pictures and videos

### **Purpose** : Allows the app to take pictures and videos with the camera.

[image]
[image]

Now, look at the Chrome browser permissions.
[image]

Yes, It has a permission to access camera (Take pictures and videos).
That's why it works nicely when open salesforce1 via chrome browser.
So we have to wait until the salesforce android developer will add this permission to salesforce1 app.